# getting already posted post fields and updating them using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I'm working on laravel, want to edit post having multiple fields to edit.
**I've successfully done this with my post's body field , want to achieve with the other two.**

Related `controller` code:

```
$post->body=$data['body'];
$post->state = $data['state'];
$post->problem_domain = $data['problem_domain'];
$post->update();
return response()->json(['new_body'=>$post->body],500);
```

`blade` from where the earlier data needs to be fetched:

```
<article class="post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
    <p> {{ $post->body }} </p>
    <p> <b> Region: </b> {{ $post->state }} &nbsp <b> Problem Domain: </b>
    {{ $post->problem_domain}}</p>
    <div class="info">
       posted by <b>{{ $post->user->name }}</b>  on 
       <b>{{ $post->created_at }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="interaction">
      <a href="#" class="like">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first()->like == 1 ? 'You like this post':'Like':'Like'}} </a>
      <a href="#" class="like">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first()->like == 0 ? 'You don\'t like this post':'Dislike':'Dislike'}}</a>
      @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
        <a href="#" class="edit"  >Edit</a>
```

and finally my `js file`,please look at the format for `body` which is correct and want to do same for other two

```
var postId=0;
var postBodyElement=null;
$('.post').find('.interaction').find('.edit').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    postBodyElement=event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    var postBody=postBodyElement.textContent;
    postId=event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    $('#post-body').val(postBody);
    $('#edit-modal').modal();
});
$('#modal-save').on('click',function()
    {  
        $.ajax(
            {
            method : 'POST',
            url :  urlEdit,
            data: {body: $('#post-body').val(), state: $('#post-state').val(), 
            problem_domain: $('#post-problem_domain').val(), postId: postId, _token: token}
         })
        .done(function(msg)
             {
                 $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
                 $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
             });
     }
);
```

Comment: when you set other attributes different to body, the record is not updated?

Comment: Record gets updated, but the jquery doesn't work. For instance, modal doesn't  hide after completion. I need to refresh to see the changes. @JoseRojas

Answer (score 0):

At your controller, you're only returning the body at this line:

```
return response()->json(['new_body'=>$post->body],500);
```

you should either return the complete model or the other attributes, like this:

```
return response()->json($post, 500);
```

and in your blade to update the other attributes.

Comment: I've already tried this. Problem is how to load data for dropdown that is in database for editing purpose. Code that i'm using is`var postState= postBodyElement.childNodes[5].textContent;$('#post-state').val(postState); ` and then working same as with _body_ but it doesn't work. @JoseRojas

Comment: What attribute do you want to show at the dropdown? are you using some HTML Framework? @Nitika

Comment: I'm working on editing posts using modal window of bootstrap. My post contains the region from the user through the dropdown. I want to access the region content of post at time of editing and return respose to json. @JoseRojas

Comment: But you have that code at the click event, that means this execute when the user click on div with class interaction and not when the server responses. @Nikita

Comment: No it works when modal's save is triggered before that when edit is clicked which will give route to it. Anyways, that's not the problem since i'm able to update my work but the problem is i'm not getting selected dropdown value in the modal window. @JoseRojas

Comment: Can you post your modal HTML please? @Nitika

Comment: Whole code is too long, related _select_ statement goes like:   `<select name="post-state" id="post-state">
                       <option value="">------------Select State------------</option>
                      <option value="Andaman and Nicobar Islands">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                      <option value="Andhra Pradesh">Andhra Pradesh</option> </select>`@JoseRojas